# Invalid identifier Error when doing to_sql sqlalchemy in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting below error when doing df.to_sql in oracle db I checked all column names.I tried with other tables  and dataframes having less columns it worked but for this particular table I am getting error

```
    Exception has occurred: DatabaseError
(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00904: "CCSD_CLI_CD": invalid identifier
[SQL: INSERT INTO "NCSUSR.COLL_CLIENT_SUBMISSION_DTLS" ("CCSD_BATCH_DT", "CCSD_CM_PAN_NO", "CCSD_TM_PAN_NO", "CCSD_CP_CODE", "CCSD_CP_PAN_NO", "CCSD_CLI_PAN_NO", "CCSD_ACCOUNT_TYPE", "CCSD_SEGMENT_INDICATOR", "CCSD_UCC", "CCSD_CP_FIN_LEDGER_BAL_A", "CCSD_CP_FIN_LEDGER_BAL_B", "CCSD_CP_FIN_PEAK_LEDGER_BAL_C", "CCSD_CP_BG", "CCSD_CP_FDR", "CCSD_CP_APR_SEC_CASH_COM", "CCSD_CP_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM", "CCSD_CP_NON_APR_SEC", "CCSD_CP_CC_APR_COMM", "CCSD_CP_OTHR_COLL", "CCSD_TM_CRED_ENTY_LEDGER_EPI", "CCSD_TM_POOL_ACCOUNT", "CCSD_TM_CASH_RETAINED", "CCSD_TM_BG", "CCSD_TM_FDR", "CCSD_TM_APR_SEC_CASH_COM", "CCSD_TM_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM", "CCSD_TM_NON_APR_SEC", "CCSD_TM_CC_APR_COMM", "CCSD_TM_OTHR_COLL", "CCSD_CM_CASH_PLACED", "CCSD_CM_BG", "CCSD_CM_FDR", "CCSD_CM_APR_SEC_CASH_COM", "CCSD_CM_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM", "CCSD_CM_NON_APR_SEC", "CCSD_CM_OTHR_COLL", "CCSD_CM_CASH_RETAINED", "CCSD_CM_RTD_BG", "CCSD_CM_RTD_FDR", "CCSD_CM_RTD_APR_SEC_CASH_COM", "CCSD_CM_RTD_APR_SEC_N_CASH_COM", "CCSD_CM_RTD_NON_APR_SEC", "CCSD_CM_RTD_CC_APR_COMM", "CCSD_CM_RTD_OTHR_COLL", "CCSD_NCCL_CASH_PLACED", "CCSD_NCCL_BG", "CCSD_NCCL_FDR", "CCSD_NCCL_APR_SEC_CASH_COM", "CCSD_NCCL_APRV_SEC_NON_CASH_COM", "CCSD_NCCL_CC_APR_COMM", "CCSD_CM_ID", "CCSD_TM_ID", "CCSD_CLI_CD", "CCSD_ID", "CCSD_FILE_ID", "CCSD_EMAIL_FLAG", "CCSD_SMS_FLAG", "CCSD_STATUS", "CCSD_CREATED_DT", "CCSD_CREATED_BY", "CCSD_MODIFIED_DT", "CCSD_MODIFIED_BY") VALUES (:CCSD_BATCH_DT, :CCSD_CM_PAN_NO, :CCSD_TM_PAN_NO, :CCSD_CP_CODE, :CCSD_CP_PAN_NO, :CCSD_CLI_PAN_NO, :CCSD_ACCOUNT_TYPE, :CCSD_SEGMENT_INDICATOR, :CCSD_UCC, :CCSD_CP_FIN_LEDGER_BAL_A, :CCSD_CP_FIN_LEDGER_BAL_B, :CCSD_CP_FIN_PEAK_LEDGER_BAL_C, :CCSD_CP_BG, :CCSD_CP_FDR, :CCSD_CP_APR_SEC_CASH_COM, :CCSD_CP_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM, :CCSD_CP_NON_APR_SEC, :CCSD_CP_CC_APR_COMM, :CCSD_CP_OTHR_COLL, :CCSD_TM_CRED_ENTY_LEDGER_EPI, :CCSD_TM_POOL_ACCOUNT, :CCSD_TM_CASH_RETAINED, :CCSD_TM_BG, :CCSD_TM_FDR, :CCSD_TM_APR_SEC_CASH_COM, :CCSD_TM_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM, :CCSD_TM_NON_APR_SEC, :CCSD_TM_CC_APR_COMM, :CCSD_TM_OTHR_COLL, :CCSD_CM_CASH_PLACED, :CCSD_CM_BG, :CCSD_CM_FDR, :CCSD_CM_APR_SEC_CASH_COM, :CCSD_CM_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM, :CCSD_CM_NON_APR_SEC, :CCSD_CM_OTHR_COLL, :CCSD_CM_CASH_RETAINED, :CCSD_CM_RTD_BG, :CCSD_CM_RTD_FDR, :CCSD_CM_RTD_APR_SEC_CASH_COM, :CCSD_CM_RTD_APR_SEC_N_CASH_COM, :CCSD_CM_RTD_NON_APR_SEC, :CCSD_CM_RTD_CC_APR_COMM, :CCSD_CM_RTD_OTHR_COLL, :CCSD_NCCL_CASH_PLACED, :CCSD_NCCL_BG, :CCSD_NCCL_FDR, :CCSD_NCCL_APR_SEC_CASH_COM, :CCSD_NCCL_APRV_SEC_NON_CASH_COM, :CCSD_NCCL_CC_APR_COMM, :CCSD_CM_ID, :CCSD_TM_ID, :CCSD_CLI_CD, :CCSD_ID, :CCSD_FILE_ID, :CCSD_EMAIL_FLAG, :CCSD_SMS_FLAG, :CCSD_STATUS, :CCSD_CREATED_DT, :CCSD_CREATED_BY, :CCSD_MODIFIED_DT, :CCSD_MODIFIED_BY)]
[parameters: {'CCSD_BATCH_DT': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 30, 0, 0), 'CCSD_CM_PAN_NO': 'AAACK1581D', 'CCSD_TM_PAN_NO': 'AAACK1581D', 'CCSD_CP_CODE': 'M', 'CCSD_CP_PAN_NO': 'M', 'CCSD_CLI_PAN_NO': 'AAACC3269J', 'CCSD_ACCOUNT_TYPE': 'C', 'CCSD_SEGMENT_INDICATOR': 'CO', 'CCSD_UCC': 'TEST2', 'CCSD_CP_FIN_LEDGER_BAL_A': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CP_FIN_LEDGER_BAL_B': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CP_FIN_PEAK_LEDGER_BAL_C': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CP_BG': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CP_FDR': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CP_APR_SEC_CASH_COM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CP_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CP_NON_APR_SEC': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CP_CC_APR_COMM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CP_OTHR_COLL': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_TM_CRED_ENTY_LEDGER_EPI': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_TM_POOL_ACCOUNT': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_TM_CASH_RETAINED': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_TM_BG': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_TM_FDR': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_TM_APR_SEC_CASH_COM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_TM_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_TM_NON_APR_SEC': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_TM_CC_APR_COMM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_TM_OTHR_COLL': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_CASH_PLACED': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_BG': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_FDR': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_APR_SEC_CASH_COM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_NON_APR_SEC': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_OTHR_COLL': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_CASH_RETAINED': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_RTD_BG': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_RTD_FDR': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_RTD_APR_SEC_CASH_COM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_RTD_APR_SEC_N_CASH_COM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_RTD_NON_APR_SEC': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_RTD_CC_APR_COMM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_RTD_OTHR_COLL': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_NCCL_CASH_PLACED': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_NCCL_BG': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_NCCL_FDR': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_NCCL_APR_SEC_CASH_COM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_NCCL_APRV_SEC_NON_CASH_COM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_NCCL_CC_APR_COMM': 123000000.0, 'CCSD_CM_ID': 'M50155', 'CCSD_TM_ID': '00155', 'CCSD_CLI_CD': 'CQG76', 'CCSD_ID': 2, 'CCSD_FILE_ID': 1, 'CCSD_EMAIL_FLAG': 'N', 'CCSD_SMS_FLAG': 'N', 'CCSD_STATUS': 'Y', 'CCSD_CREATED_DT': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 30, 0, 0), 'CCSD_CREATED_BY': 'SYSTEM', 'CCSD_MODIFIED_DT': None, 'CCSD_MODIFIED_BY': None}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "D:\Alok\CR06645_PythonCode\insertdf.py", line 76, in InsertIntoDB
    FinalDataframe.to_sql('NCSUSR.COLL_CLIENT_SUBMISSION_DTLS', engine,index=False, if_exists='append', dtype=dtyp, chunksize=10**4)
  File "D:\Alok\CR06645_PythonCode\CR6645script.py", line 940, in CollateralValidation
    bVal=insertdf.InsertIntoDB(FinalDataframe)
  File "D:\Alok\CR06645_PythonCode\CR6645script.py", line 37, in readCSV
    CollateralValidation(dfFileNames)
```

My code:

```
    def InsertIntoDB(FinalDataframe):
    try:
        engine.connect()
        FinalDataframe['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(FinalDataframe['Date'])
        FinalDataframe['CCSD_CREATED_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(FinalDataframe['CCSD_CREATED_DT'])
        FinalDataframe['CCSD_MODIFIED_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(FinalDataframe['CCSD_MODIFIED_DT'])
        dtyp = {c:types.VARCHAR(FinalDataframe[c].str.len().max())
        for c in FinalDataframe.columns[FinalDataframe.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}
        NewColumnName=['CCSD_BATCH_DT','CCSD_CM_PAN_NO','CCSD_TM_PAN_NO','CCSD_CP_CODE','CCSD_CP_PAN_NO','CCSD_CLI_PAN_NO','CCSD_ACCOUNT_TYPE','CCSD_SEGMENT_INDICATOR','CCSD_UCC','CCSD_CP_FIN_LEDGER_BAL_A','CCSD_CP_FIN_LEDGER_BAL_B','CCSD_CP_FIN_PEAK_LEDGER_BAL_C','CCSD_CP_BG','CCSD_CP_FDR','CCSD_CP_APR_SEC_CASH_COM','CCSD_CP_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM','CCSD_CP_NON_APR_SEC','CCSD_CP_CC_APR_COMM','CCSD_CP_OTHR_COLL','CCSD_TM_CRED_ENTY_LEDGER_EPI','CCSD_TM_POOL_ACCOUNT','CCSD_TM_CASH_RETAINED','CCSD_TM_BG','CCSD_TM_FDR','CCSD_TM_APR_SEC_CASH_COM','CCSD_TM_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM','CCSD_TM_NON_APR_SEC','CCSD_TM_CC_APR_COMM','CCSD_TM_OTHR_COLL','CCSD_CM_CASH_PLACED','CCSD_CM_BG','CCSD_CM_FDR','CCSD_CM_APR_SEC_CASH_COM','CCSD_CM_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM','CCSD_CM_NON_APR_SEC','CCSD_CM_OTHR_COLL','CCSD_CM_CASH_RETAINED','CCSD_CM_RTD_BG','CCSD_CM_RTD_FDR','CCSD_CM_RTD_APR_SEC_CASH_COM','CCSD_CM_RTD_APR_SEC_N_CASH_COM','CCSD_CM_RTD_NON_APR_SEC','CCSD_CM_RTD_NON_APR_SEC','CCSD_CM_RTD_CC_APR_COMM','CCSD_CM_RTD_OTHR_COLL','CCSD_NCCL_CASH_PLACED','CCSD_NCCL_BG','CCSD_NCCL_FDR','CCSD_NCCL_APR_SEC_CASH_COM','CCSD_NCCL_APRV_SEC_NON_CASH_COM','CCSD_NCCL_CC_APR_COMM','CCSD_CM_ID','CCSD_TM_ID','CCSD_CLI_CD','CCSD_ID','CCSD_FILE_ID','CCSD_EMAIL_FLAG','CCSD_SMS_FLAG','CCSD_STATUS','CCSD_CREATED_DT','CCSD_CREATED_BY','CCSD_MODIFIED_DT','CCSD_MODIFIED_BY']
        FinalDataframe.columns = NewColumnName
        print(FinalDataframe,FinalDataframe.dtypes,FinalDataframe.info())
        print("dtyp",dtyp)
        print("before")
        start_time = time.time()
        FinalDataframe.to_sql('NCSUSR.COLL_CLIENT_SUBMISSION_DTLS', engine,index=False, if_exists='append', dtype=dtyp, chunksize=10**4)
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        print("successful")
    except exception as ex :
        print(ex)
```

The New column Names matches too .

My dataframe :

```
CCSD_BATCH_DT CCSD_CM_PAN_NO  CCSD_TM_PAN_NO   CCSD_CP_CODE   CCSD_CP_PAN_NO   CCSD_CLI_PAN_NO   CCSD_ACCOUNT_TYPE   CCSD_SEGMENT_INDICATOR   CCSD_UCC   CCSD_CP_FIN_LEDGER_BAL_A   CCSD_CP_FIN_LEDGER_BAL_B   CCSD_CP_FIN_PEAK_LEDGER_BAL_C   CCSD_CP_BG   CCSD_CP_FDR   CCSD_CP_APR_SEC_CASH_COM   CCSD_CP_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM   CCSD_CP_NON_APR_SEC   CCSD_CP_CC_APR_COMM   CCSD_CP_OTHR_COLL   CCSD_TM_CRED_ENTY_LEDGER_EPI   CCSD_TM_POOL_ACCOUNT   CCSD_TM_CASH_RETAINED   CCSD_TM_BG   CCSD_TM_FDR   CCSD_TM_APR_SEC_CASH_COM   CCSD_TM_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM   CCSD_TM_NON_APR_SEC   CCSD_TM_CC_APR_COMM   CCSD_TM_OTHR_COLL   CCSD_CM_CASH_PLACED   CCSD_CM_BG   CCSD_CM_FDR   CCSD_CM_APR_SEC_CASH_COM   CCSD_CM_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM   CCSD_CM_NON_APR_SEC   CCSD_CM_OTHR_COLL   CCSD_CM_CASH_RETAINED   CCSD_CM_RTD_BG   CCSD_CM_RTD_FDR   CCSD_CM_RTD_APR_SEC_CASH_COM   CCSD_CM_RTD_APR_SEC_N_CASH_COM   CCSD_CM_RTD_NON_APR_SEC   CCSD_CM_RTD_NON_APR_SEC   CCSD_CM_RTD_CC_APR_COMM   CCSD_CM_RTD_OTHR_COLL   CCSD_NCCL_CASH_PLACED   CCSD_NCCL_BG   CCSD_NCCL_FDR   CCSD_NCCL_APR_SEC_CASH_COM   CCSD_NCCL_APRV_SEC_NON_CASH_COM   CCSD_NCCL_CC_APR_COMM   CCSD_CM_ID   CCSD_TM_ID   CCSD_CLI_CD   CCSD_ID   CCSD_FILE_ID   CCSD_EMAIL_FLAG   CCSD_SMS_FLAG   CCSD_STATUS   CCSD_CREATED_DT   CCSD_CREATED_BY   CCSD_MODIFIED_DT   CCSD_MODIFIED_BY
30-09-2021 AAACK1581D AAACK1581D M  M  AAACC3269J   C   CO   TEST2   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   123000000.0   M50155   00155   CQG76   2   1   N   N   Y   2021-09-30   SYSTEM NaT NaN
```

Been Trying for solution for long time now . Need help !!!

DB Table DESC:

```
    desc NCSUSR.COLL_CLIENT_SUBMISSION_DTLS  
Name                                          Null     Type                                                                                                                                                                                                                
--------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
CCSD_ID                                                NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                              
CCSD_FILE_ID                                           NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                              
CCSD_BATCH_DT                                          DATE                                                                                                                                                                                                                
CCSD_CM_ID                                             VARCHAR2(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_PAN_NO                                         VARCHAR2(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_TM_ID                                             VARCHAR2(6)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
CCSD_TM_PAN_NO                                         VARCHAR2(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CP_CODE                                           VARCHAR2(12)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CP_PAN_NO                                         VARCHAR2(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CLI_CD                                            VARCHAR2(12)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CLI_PAN_NO                                        VARCHAR2(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_ACCOUNT_TYPE                                      VARCHAR2(1)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
CCSD_SEGMENT_INDICATOR                                 VARCHAR2(3)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
CCSD_UCC                                               VARCHAR2(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CP_FIN_LEDGER_BAL_A                               NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CP_FIN_LEDGER_BAL_B                               NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CP_FIN_PEAK_LEDGER_BAL_C                          NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CP_BG                                             NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CP_FDR                                            NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CP_APR_SEC_CASH_COM                               NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CP_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM                           NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CP_NON_APR_SEC                                    NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CP_CC_APR_COMM                                    NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CP_OTHR_COLL                                      NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_TM_CRED_ENTY_LEDGER_EPI                           NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_TM_POOL_ACCOUNT                                   NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_TM_CASH_RETAINED                                  NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_TM_BG                                             NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_TM_FDR                                            NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_TM_APR_SEC_CASH_COM                               NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_TM_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM                           NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_TM_NON_APR_SEC                                    NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_TM_CC_APR_COMM                                    NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_TM_OTHR_COLL                                      NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_CASH_PLACED                                    NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_BG                                             NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_FDR                                            NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_APR_SEC_CASH_COM                               NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_APR_SEC_NON_CASH_COM                           NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_NON_APR_SEC                                    NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_CC_APR_COMM                                    NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_OTHR_COLL                                      NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_CASH_RETAINED                                  NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_RTD_BG                                         NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_RTD_FDR                                        NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_RTD_APR_SEC_CASH_COM                           NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_RTD_APR_SEC_N_CASH_COM                         NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_RTD_NON_APR_SEC                                NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_RTD_CC_APR_COMM                                NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CM_RTD_OTHR_COLL                                  NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_NCCL_CASH_PLACED                                  NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_NCCL_BG                                           NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_NCCL_FDR                                          NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_NCCL_APR_SEC_CASH_COM                             NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_NCCL_APRV_SEC_NON_CASH_COM                        NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_NCCL_CC_APR_COMM                                  NUMBER(20,3)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_EMAIL_FLAG                                        VARCHAR2(2)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
CCSD_SMS_FLAG                                          VARCHAR2(2)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
CCSD_STATUS                                            VARCHAR2(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_CREATED_DT                                        DATE                                                                                                                                                                                                                
CCSD_CREATED_BY                                        VARCHAR2(25)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
CCSD_MODIFIED_DT                                       DATE                                                                                                                                                                                                                
CCSD_MODIFIED_BY                                       VARCHAR2(25)
```

Comment: Error says that column CCSD_CLI_CD doesn't exist in that table. Please, post table's description - not your own interpretation, but from the database (i.e. result of selecting USER_TAB_COLUMNS).

Comment: @Littlefoot Updated my question .

Comment: As you said, you checked column names and it looks OK. Unfortunately, that's my conclusion as well. I was (kind of) hoping of column name created with double quotes and mixed letter case or just a typo, but - as far as I can see - everything looks just fine. Sorry, I wouldn't know what's wrong.

Comment: @Littlefoot I also tried 'df=pd.read_sql("select query")' and and then 'df.to_sql()' but still same error .